# How to reset form onSubmit in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form built with Formik. And I would like to reset/ empty it after submit. I've tried to add `resetForm()`, but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    setSubmitting(false);
    resetForm();
  }, 400);
}}
```

And a live example https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-form-8sw24.

Where is my mistake and how can I reset/ empty form onSubmit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add `value={values.phone}` to the input as I'm using a custom input. After that `resetForm()` is working.

Comment: Glad you found it, I was trying to play around with your codesandbox to see what the issue was.